# PHP add comma and space unless end of foreach

Tags: php

I am using this code

```
<?php
foreach($rows as $row) {
echo "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>, ";
}
?>
```

The problem is that the comma and space (`,<space>`) are added to even the last `$row`. What is the simplest method to prevent this? I had an idea to check the size of the array etc. but not sure if this would be over complicating it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this -

```
<?php
$links= array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $links[]= "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>";
}

echo implode(', ', $links);
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$total = count($rows);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>";
    $i++;
    if($i < $total)
       echo ",";
}
?>
```

Or **RiggsFolly**'s answer is another option.

Comment: I do love counting Cows, get me off to sleep in no time. hehehe

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do the same too!! You have already seen that.. ;)

Comment: everyone likes to count cows... :) bros @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler solution

```
<?php
$htm = '';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $htm .= "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>, ";
}
rtrim($htm,', ');
echo $htm;
?>
```

If you want to get complicated then you could do :-

```
<?php
$crows = count($rows) - 1;
foreach($rows as $i => $row) {
    echo "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>";
    echo ( $crows > $i ) ? ', ' : '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with strings with two ways:

1) Use `rtrim()`

```
<?php
$str = '';
foreach($rows as $row) {
$str .= "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>, ";
}
echo rtrim($str, ', ');
?>
```

2) Take an array of links and `implode()` by space and comma.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
$arr[] =  "<a href=index.html?id=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</a>, ";
}
echo implode(', ', $arr);
?>
```